# ASP.Net Core 2.2 test project has no controller code for creating external Facebook login and no UI button like the guide shows

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, facebook-login, angular-social-login

I need to see how the controller code is implemented for external logins using Facebook and/or Google. So I'm following these two MS pages [guide1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio-code) and [guide2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to create a test app to test external logins (Fb/Google). But after creating both a Asp.Net Core 2.2 and 3.0 app using the instructions:

> dotnet new webapp -o WebApp1 -au Individual -uld
>   code -r WebApp1

None of the code shows a Facebook button like the one in the guide and I can't find any code behind associated with it either! I'm looking for some controller code that shows how I would add the external user to the AspNetUsers table for Identity.

Maybe there's a github repo that has the code that I can look at?

Here is what I see.

[image]

Here's what the guide shows.

[image]

Comment: have you looked at the `_LoginPartial`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I just looked at it but I don't think that will help. I don't need help with Identity, I need with the implementation code that shows me how to register and login a Social account from Facebook or Google, with Identity! I didn't see that in your link.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [Azure Active Directory B2C (ADB2C)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview) if you are planning on integrating external authentication providers.  This would save you having to integrate with each provider (Facebook, Google, etc) individually.  The configuration is then all done from the Azure portal.

You can download code samples from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/code-samples).

Answer (score 0):

The code already exists, but you have to register the external providers you intend to use. For [Facebook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-facebook-authentication) for example:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
{
    facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
    facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
});
```

Once you've configured one or more external providers, the buttons light up on the login view.

Comment: "The buttons light up" the buttons don't even exist in the code. I searched around for it, but don't see it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core 2.1 and later provides ASP.NET Core Identity as a Razor Class Library. Applications that include Identity can apply the scaffolder to selectively add the source code contained in the Identity Razor Class Library (RCL). See document : [Scaffold Identity in ASP.NET Core projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio) .

After scaffolding identity source files to your application , you could find all the identity related codes . For external login , you could check the `ExternalLogin.cshtml.cs` file inside `Areas/Identity/Pages/Account` folder . In function `OnGetCallbackAsync` you will find identity will check the external login user information and confirm a local user is associated with external user , if yes , sign in user ; If no, it will redirect user to another page to ask the user to create an account in local database .

To enable external login , as [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-facebook-authentication) show ,you need register the external providers you intend to use .